# How does Javascript equality operator works?

Tags: javascript, equality

I was just trying something in javascript and came across this scenario for the javascript equality operator, which baffled me

[image]

My questions are,

1) Why `""==0` is true ?

2) If `"0"==0` and `""==0` is `true` then why `""=="0"` is `false` ?

Any explanation and the pointers for more reading will be great.

Comment: Like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: I'm really surprised the title box didn't pop up ten different duplicates when you posted this question.

Comment: Probably the best read on the topic of loose vs. strict equality & type coercion - [here.](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md)